# Is there any way to generate screenshot of a youtube video from a specific time?

Tags: html, flash, youtube, youtube-api, video-streaming

Lets say there is a function `getScreenShot`. We call it like:

```
scrShot=getScreenShot(videoID, time, quality)
```

And it gives us a screenshot of the video from the specified `time` (like 1:23) in specified `quality` (like 720p).

Is there any possible way to do it automatically without loading the full video.

Comment: Sounds like a violation of the YouTube TOS.

Comment: You can access the couple screenshots Youtube generates. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the actual screenshot part, but I imagine you can [seek to the time by setting .currentTime](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp) and then use [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1052944/73454) to hide the various controls, giving you an unobstructed image.

The real question to answer is if you can capture a screenshot. I would guess not due to privacy concerns?